# How to define variables in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

In my PHP project I'm using static-file server (ex img.domain.com).
That server path I have is  stored in `$config` table. (`$this->config['file_server']`).

During developement static server-file is local server (main root).

Problem is that when using it I don't get path suggestions (ctrl+space) eg:

```
<img src="<?=$this->config['file_server'];?>image.png">
```

Can I make phpstorm to interprate `$this->config['file_server']` as `"/"` sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the same question on jetbrains forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5515452#5515452

Anwser from Andriy Bazanov"

> Hi there,   You cannot.
>   The actual inspection is disabled in such
>   situations on purpose (to avoid false warnings .. since it is unknown
>   in advance what that path would be). IDE currently does not allow to
>   provide value or return type for individual array elements anyway   On
>   another hand -- it works just fine if leading "/" is actually present,
>   i.e. config['file_server'];?>/image.png"> (in such
>   case path completion works)